# TFS 2010 - Import work items using Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

I have a list of bugs in Excel (exported from an in-house bug tracker). These are in various states - active, deferred, resolved etc.
I am able to use the 'Team' menu -> New List in Excel and map my columns. But it seems to work only for new items. If work-item type is 'Bug' then state can only be 'Active'.
This is no good for old work-items that might have state as resolved and need to be imported.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible states are defined in the process template. As far as you didn't mention your process template I guess that you have a process template where new bugs can only have the state active.

To import "new" bugs with different states than active you have to change your process template to allow the creation of new bugs with any state as start state.

Comment: OK. A slight problem is that the current process template is good for adding new bugs, i.e. once these old bugs are in, people will use the current process template to add new bugs.
I suppose I could change it, import the bugs and change it back to the original. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Either this or you import the bugs without mapping the state column and afterwards map the state column and then update all bugs. Don't know if that works.